# Connecing a stereo reverb pedal into two separate amplifier fx loops

Tags: stereo, amplifier, reverb, guitar, signal-routing

I am using a dual chain Acus acoustic guitar preamplifier equipped with 2 separate FX loops for each channel.

https://www.acus-sound.it/en/preamplification/16-stagepre2-di.html

I would like to connect it to an EDX Cathedral stereo reverb pedal:

https://www.bax-shop.fr/reverb-delay/electro-harmonix-cathedral-stereo-reverb-pedale-d-effets

The both devices should be connected by means of the following connection routine:

L channel  of the reverb pedal to the first FX loop of the preamplifier;

R channel of the reverb pedal to the second FX loop of the preamplifier;

May I expect good stereo imaging with such setup? Alternatively, would it be possible to connect the both fx loops using only one input/output pair of the pedal, thus using only two cables for send and return?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Maître! I attempted to edit to clarify a bit, but as I don't know much about guitar effects and routing, I could only do so much. I think it would be helpful if you could add links to the actual devices you're using. Thanks and welcome!

Comment: Hey , thank you very much for your kind feedback! I ve just edited my post with additional specs of the devices

Comment: We do NOT know how the stereo reverb pedal makes the reverb. Nobody guarantees there's 2 full CHs. It can well cook together the L and R input signal in that process and output the reverberation mixture to the right channel a little delayed when compared to what the left output gets - so the reverb may contain stuff from your both amp outputs. If they are made of the same guitar or mic signal the result can contain intolerable  frequency cancellations. Forget the alternative setup. For stereo imaging effect the  outputs of the reverb must be fed to separate speakers or stereo recording tracks.

Comment: Right thank you ! Anyway in principle the setup using separate channels of the preamplifier associated with separate channel of the reverb should work and will not damage preamplifier, won’t it ?

Comment: I thought you'd be able to pan returned FX left/right, but looks like you can't.

Comment: Those signal voltage levels (less than one volt, surely through resistances at least tens of ohms) do not damage circuits., not even when accidentally shorted. Speaker outputs and power supply lines are totally different cases. One thing should be known: Some power supplies, probably all of them which are based on switchmode technologies, have capacitive connection to mains AC voltage lines. Misusing them can in some cases inject the mains AC voltage to signal connectors. It comes through capacitors, but electronic circuits may be burned. Sorrowless people have burned valuable devices with it.

Comment: (Continued) That has happened in front of my eyes when people have used computer devices and audio equipment together and tried to avoid ground loops. In some case nothing was destroyded, only the singer or the guitarist got furious due the small, but annoying electric shocks.  Understanding that field is essential to keep one's equipment live, but that's not asked this time.

Comment: Right thank you very much!